# Can't resolve DNS name of EFS while mounting it on red hat ec2 instances using putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, amazon-efs

I am having an issue where I am unable to mount my EFS on red hat ec2 instance using the DNS names. It throws the error

> mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server us-east-1a.fs-c2aXXXX.efs.us-east-1.amazon
> aws.com: Name or service not known

I am following the instructions provided by AWS. I tried below two ways to do it and both throw the same above error. I can confirm that the DNS names are correct.

1st:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport fs-c2aXXXX.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ efs
```

2nd:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).fs-c2a7XXXX.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ /efs
```

However, if I use IP instead of DNS names, I am able to mount it just fine. So below command works.

```
mount -t nfs4 -o 
nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 10.38.X.XX:/ /efs
```

I am fine with using IP instead of DNS as long as I am able to mount it.

Now my issue is as soon as I stop and start the instance again, my mount is gone. Even after I add the below entry to the **/etc/fstab**, it doesn't do auto mount.

```
10.38.X.XXX:/ /efs efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

Can someone please help me in either resolving the issue with DNS or tell me how to auto mount using IPs?

Comment: [*"The VPC of the connecting EC2 instance must have both DNS Resolution and DNS Hostnames enabled."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-dns-name.html)  Check this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is the real answer, thanks. Also you need to restart your ec2 to affect after the modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To attach to EFS from the command line use this as your template, replacing `fs-12345678` with your id:

```
$ sudo mount -t efs fs-12345678:/ /efs
```

Use this in your `/etc/fstab` (do not add `.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` after it)

```
fs-12345678:/ /efs efs vers=4.1,rw,tls,_netdev,relatime,acl,nofail 0 0
```

The `fstab` version also turns on encryption for data transport.  Check out the resource for more information

**Resources**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-mounting.html#automount-fails

Answer (score 13):

If you have opened all security groups, network ACLs, confirmed that you are in a valid AZ and still not working; probably the VPC you created doesn't have DNS hostnames enabled, validate that you have this setting:

[image: vpc]

The default VPC that comes with your account has this enabled, others don't.

Comment: I have no idea why a private VPC had to have this enabled but enabling this allowed my ECS Fargate service to resolve the service.

Comment: @ChrisRice You had to have this enabled so the internal DNS resolution of the AWS services can work, in this case for the EFS private URL.

Comment: saved my day. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the new efs-utils dns. A walkaround would be to mount a chosen availability zone mount target ([this is probably still in development](https://github.com/aws/efs-utils/issues/10)).

To solve this, I tried to add entries for the efs in the /etc/hosts file like so;

```
[efs-az-private-ip] [efs hostname (e.g;fs-xx.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)]
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to mount on CodeBuild and running into dns issues. What "new efs-utils dns" issue are you referring to?

Comment: @nitsujri for my case, the new efs-utils DNS requirement prevented the mount of the efs across AZ's (mount point should be located within the same AZ of originating DNS request). I was only able to resolve using /etc/hosts. However, upon ensuring that the mount points were located within the same AZ, I created efs access points as well and the mounts worked fine.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-dns-name.html

Comment: that was it! I needed them to all be in the same AZ, same subnet. Once I got that it got past DNS and ran into timeout issues - allowing the NFS port was the last bit to fully connect. THANKS!